# Can't access the default gateway from my VMs using Hyper-V on a W8 Pro ASUS N76V

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, switch

- I just purchased a ASUS Notebook N76V.
- I first upgraded the OS to W8 Pro.
- I activated the Hyper-V feature.
- Everything runs fine. I can create virtual switches / Import VMs / Create new VMs / Boot my VMs.
- I configured the IP addresses / Sub-masks / default gateway
- I disabled my firewalls
- Under Hyper-V all my network adapters seem to run OK
- I've tried all the 3 types of Virtual Switches (Internal / External / Private)
- I can never access my default gateway. The only thing I can ping is the VM itself.
- I've created many virtual environments before, where my host machines were either a Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2008 R2. I've never had problems to access the default gateway and other WMs on the virtual network.
- This is the first time I'm using Hyper-V on W8, and the first time I'm using the ASUS N76V Notebook.
- Is there anything in particular I have. to configure?

Comment: Describe your virtual switch configuration and your network hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Configure every virtual network adapter to the **external** setting. They will be bridged to a physical network interface and behave as if they were connected in the same device as your physical network adapter.

If you have a DHCP server, it will serve them IP addresses. If you don't, you need to configure static IP addresses in the same subnet as the default gateway you're talking about.

Comment: Thank you Greg, Yes with the external setting it seems to work. I'm able to ping all the VMs and my host as well.
It is normal that I can't ping my default gateway (192.168.1.1)?
It seems to me that I was able to do that in previous labs, when I had a 2012 as host and a private setting.

Comment: @Nakata please register your accounts on [SF] and [SU]. You will then automatically get access to your question back, and be able to edit the original question and reply to comments on the answers.